# ASP.NET Core 3.1 deployment issue in public hosting server

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm facing the below issue when hosting my ASP.NET Core application in public hosting server. I can run the whole system without any issue in my local IIS. But when deployed to public hosting throwing the below error. web.config file is there in the folder. Hosting provider claimed the server support .NET Core 3.1.

Looking for some idea to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFqx8.png)

Comment: Have you checked the .NET CLR version of your app pool is set to `No managed code` and also ensure that the AppPool user has permissions to read from your applicaton directory

Comment: Fixed the issue. Yup done as per above. Thanks Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

> Check your **IIS** installed

[image: IIS]

> Then Install [Current .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#direct-download-current-version)

Comment: Yes Zanyar. all the above is ok. Need to configure separate application pool. Fixed the issue. Thanks man